# Cyanogenmod - new apps make bootloop

Tags: cyanogenmod, boot-loop, google-play-services

when I update some application (Telegram, Skype) my Cyanogenmod starts to glitch, Google Play, Trebushet services (when I open the application menu), Settings (when I click on the "Applications" section) stop working. 
some applications after installation generally restart the phone. some do infinite loading. Only removal via recovery helps

tried to install CM 12, 13, 14 - everywhere this problem. Everyone works, but I do not have

Ttebushet error (just open empty main screen)

```
    property debug.db.uid not set; NOT waiting for gdb.
11-29 23:43:04.671 267 267 I       DEBUG                                        HINT: adb shell setprop debug.db.uid 100000
11-29 23:43:04.671 267 267 I       DEBUG                                        HINT: adb forward tcp:5039 tcp:5039
11-29 23:43:04.776 267 267 I       DEBUG                                        *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
11-29 23:43:04.776 267 267 I       DEBUG                                        Build fingerprint: 'Micromax/Q415/Q415:5.1.1/LMY49G/C577B040:user/release-keys'
11-29 23:43:04.776 267 267 I       DEBUG                                        Revision: '0'
11-29 23:43:04.776 267 267 I       DEBUG                                        ABI: 'arm'
11-29 23:43:04.777 267 267 I       DEBUG                                        pid: 12687, tid: 12706, name: launcher-loader  >>> com.cyanogenmod.trebuchet <<<
11-29 23:43:04.777 267 267 I       DEBUG                                        signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0xdeadbaad
11-29 23:43:04.816 267 267 I       DEBUG                                        Abort message: 'invalid address or address of corrupt block 0x21 passed to dlfree'
11-29 23:43:04.819 267 267 I       DEBUG                                        r0 00000000  r1 b6e55dec  r2 deadbaad  r3 00000000
11-29 23:43:04.822 267 267 I       DEBUG                                        r4 00000021  r5 b6e570d8  r6 a1d14000  r7 00000029
11-29 23:43:04.823 267 267 I       DEBUG                                        r8 a587b36c  r9 a587b42c  sl b6d29232  fp b6d2923b
11-29 23:43:04.824 267 267 I       DEBUG                                        ip 00008000  sp a587b318  lr b6e2717b  pc b6e2717c  cpsr 600d0030
11-29 23:43:04.825 267 267 I       DEBUG                                        
11-29 23:43:04.825 267 267 I       DEBUG                                        backtrace:
11-29 23:43:04.825 267 267 I       DEBUG                                        #00 pc 0002917c  /system/lib/libc.so (dlfree+1239)
11-29 23:43:04.826 267 267 I       DEBUG                                        #01 pc 0000f363  /system/lib/libc.so (free+10)
11-29 23:43:04.827 267 267 I       DEBUG                                        #02 pc 00012ac5  /system/lib/libandroidfw.so (android::ResStringPool::uninit()+38)
11-29 23:43:04.827 267 267 I       DEBUG                                        #03 pc 000137f5  /system/lib/libandroidfw.so (android::ResXMLTree::uninit()+14)
11-29 23:43:04.828 267 267 I       DEBUG                                        #04 pc 00013813  /system/lib/libandroidfw.so (android::ResXMLTree::~ResXMLTree()+4)
11-29 23:43:04.829 267 267 I       DEBUG                                        #05 pc 000104e7  /system/lib/libandroidfw.so (android::AssetManager::getPkgName(char const*)+258)
11-29 23:43:04.829 267 267 I       DEBUG                                        #06 pc 00010549  /system/lib/libandroidfw.so (android::AssetManager::getBasePackageName(unsigned int)+68)
11-29 23:43:04.830 267 267 I       DEBUG                                        #07 pc 0008221f  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so
11-29 23:43:04.830 267 267 I       DEBUG                                        #08 pc 0027b38b  /data/dalvik-cache/arm/system@framework@boot.oat
11-29 23:43:05.372 9925 10106 I    Adreno-EGL com.aide.ui                       <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:379>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build:  (I7b941c52a8)
11-29 23:43:05.372 9925 10106 I    Adreno-EGL com.aide.ui                       OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: E031.25.03.04
11-29 23:43:05.372 9925 10106 I    Adreno-EGL com.aide.ui                       Build Date: 06/25/15 Thu
11-29 23:43:05.372 9925 10106 I    Adreno-EGL com.aide.ui                       Local Branch:
11-29 23:43:05.372 9925 10106 I    Adreno-EGL com.aide.ui                       Remote Branch:
11-29 23:43:05.372 9925 10106 I    Adreno-EGL com.aide.ui                       Local Patches:
11-29 23:43:05.372 9925 10106 I    Adreno-EGL com.aide.ui                       Reconstruct Branch:
11-29 23:43:05.373 9925 10106 I    OpenGLRenderer com.aide.ui                   Initialized EGL, version 1.4
11-29 23:43:05.662 5642 12736 W    ActivityManager                              Process com.cyanogenmod.trebuchet has crashed too many times: killing!
11-29 23:43:05.662 5642 12736 W    ActivityManager                              Force finishing activity 4 com.cyanogenmod.trebuchet/com.android.launcher3.Launcher
    11-29 23:43:05.663 267 267 I       DEBUG
```

Comment: i try install it again and see logs, wait please

Comment: There seems to be a solution for this over at xda.
https://forum.xda-developers.com/general/help/bootloop-updating-apps-telegram-t3700773/page2